# Issue with While Loop in SQL function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm writing a function that should add each line item quantity multiplied by its unit cost and then iterating through the entire pickticket (PT). I don't get an error when altering the function in SQL Server or when running it, but it gives me a 0 as the output each time.

---

Here is an example:

---

[PT 1]

[Line 1 - QTY: 10 Unit Cost: $5.00] total should be = $50.00

[Line 2 - QTY: 5  Unit Cost: $2.50] total should be = $12.50

The function should output - $62.50

---

Not really sure what I'm missing here, but would appreciate the help.

```
Alter Function fn_CalculateAllocatedPTPrice
  (@psPickTicket   TPickTicketNo)
  -------------------------------
  Returns TInteger
As 
Begin
  Declare
    @iReturn           TInteger,
    @iTotalLineNumbers TInteger,
    @iIndex            TInteger,
    @fTotalCost        TFloat;

    set @iIndex = 1;
    set @iTotalLineNumbers = (ISNULL((select top 1 PickLineNo
                             from tblPickTicketDtl
                             where PickTicketNo = @psPickTicket
                             order by PickLineNo desc), 0)) /* This returns the highest line number */

    while(@iIndex <= @iTotalLineNumbers)
      BEGIN
        /* This should be adding up the total cost of each line item on the PT */
        set @fTotalCost = @fTotalCost + (ISNULL((select  SUM(P.RetailUnitPrice*P.UnitsOrdered)
                        from tblPickTicketDtl P
                        left outer join tblCase C on (P.PickTicketNo = C.PickTicketNo)
                        where P.PickTicketNo = @psPickTcket
                        and P.PickLineNo = @iIndex
                        and C.CaseStatus in ('A','G','K','E','L','S')), 0))
        set @iIndex = @iIndex + 1;
      END
    set @iReturn = @fTotalCost;
    _Return:
  Return(@iReturn);
End /* fn_CalculateAllocatedPTPrice */
```

Comment: What you are missing is that you shouldn't use a `WHILE` loop in SQL unless you really have to, and you shouldn't use scalar User Defined functions unless you really have to. Why does this need a loop, why can you not just use simple aggregation? What *we* are missing is proper sample data formatted as a table or as `CREATE` `INSERT` statements.

Comment: Yes it's fine to encapsulate a process in a function for reusability and readability, ideally this would a *table-valued function* with no need for any looping - indeed if there is any single place to avoid a RBAR process, it's in a function - or a trigger... or well anywhere really.

Answer (score 3):

It seems simple aggregation should suffice

A few points to note:

- `WHILE` loops and cursors are very rarely needed in SQL. You should stick to set-based solutions, and if you find yourself writing a loop you shuold question your code from its beginnings.
- Scalar functions are slow and inefficient. Use an *inline* Table function, which you can correlate with your main query either with an `APPLY` or a subquery
- Your `left join` becomes an `inner join` because of the `where` predicate
- User defined types are not normally a good idea (when they are just aliasing system types)

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION fn_CalculateAllocatedPTPrice
  (@psPickTicket   TPickTicketNo)

RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN

SELECT fTotalCost = ISNULL((
    SELECT SUM(P.RetailUnitPrice * P.UnitsOrdered)
    from tblPickTicketDtl P
    join tblCase C on (P.PickTicketNo = C.PickTicketNo)
    where P.PickTicketNo = @psPickTcket
      and C.CaseStatus in ('A','G','K','E','L','S')
    ), 0);

GO
```